# Google recaptcha v3 is not showing if URL contents url encoding

Tags: urlencode, recaptcha-v3, windows-1251

I have successfully installed google recaptcha v3 on my site and there is some strange thing: it works fine on every url like "site.com/url" or "site.com/url.php" or "site.com/url.html" but it does not work on url that contents url-encoding symbols like site.com/%FE.html. What can be the reason of this problem? By the way, %FE is russian "ю" symbol in windows-1251...Recaptcha can't work with this url-encoded symbols?

Comment: Also, i can mention, that i use recaptcha v3 for protecting my forms from parsing - and there is get method in my forms

Answer (score 0):

So, i have found the right solution. Recaptcha v3 uses *decodeURIComponent* function to work with urls, so it can't decode urls (throwing an error 'URI malformed'), that were encoded with *URI-encoding*. Now i use *encodeURIComponent* for generating my urls and everything works good.

For example, encoded russian letter 'ю' with *encodeURIComponent* is "%D1%8E" (while it is "%FE" in url-encode)